# Data passed to angular d3 directive not arriving in time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, d3.js

I am doing a mongodb query and passing results to an angular directive that contains d3 chart logic. I am using a controller to pass myData to scope, and can print it in HTML just fine, but the directive does not load - **I think myData is not resolved in time because the query is not finished yet.**

This has been discussed in other threads, but very specific to problems that I find difficult to apply in this context.

**I am generally wondering how I should approach this problem.** I am pretty new to Angular and d3, so I would appreciate any guidance.

The HTML. Here "lsk" can be accessed nicely, and "myData" can also be accessed directly in the html. However, the  directive does not load.

```
<div ng-hide="editMode" class="container">
  <div>
    <p="lsk.value1">Verdi1: {{ lsk.value1 }} </p>
    <p="lsk.value2">Verdi2: {{ lsk.value2 }} </p>
    <p="lsk.value3">Verdi3: {{ lsk.value3 }} </p>
    <p>
      <button style="margin-top:20px" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleEdit()">Edit</button>
      <a style="margin-top:20px" class="btn btn-default" href="#/">Back</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div>MyData: {{ myData }} Length: {{ myData.length }}</div>
<div>
  <bars-chart chart-data="myData"></bars-chart>
</div>
```

The controller (extract):

```
.controller("EditLskController", function($scope, $routeParams, Lsks) {
    Lsks.getLsk($routeParams.lskId).then(function(doc) {

        //This works, lsk can be referenced in my form.
        $scope.lsk = doc.data;

        //This does not work for the d3 chart, but the
        //values can be referenced in a div separately.
        $scope.myData = [doc.data.value1,doc.data.value2,doc.data.value3];
    }, function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });

    //By uncommenting here I get static data that does render the d3 directive
   // $scope.myData = [1,10,30,40,60, 80, 20,50];
})
```

The service (extract):

```
.service("Lsks", function($http) {
    this.getLsks = function() {
        return $http.get("/lsks").
            then(function(response) {
                return response;
            }, function(response) {
                alert("Error finding lsks.");
            });
    }
    this.getLsk = function(lskId) {
        var url = "/lsks/" + lskId;
        return $http.get(url).
            then(function(response) {
                return response;
            }, function(response) {
                alert("Error finding this lsk.");
            });
    }
```

The directive is taken from this tutorial: http://odiseo.net/angularjs/proper-use-of-d3-js-with-angular-directives. It works fine.

```
   //camel cased directive name
   //in your HTML, this will be named as bars-chart
   .directive('barsChart', function ($parse) {
     //explicitly creating a directive definition variable
     //this may look verbose but is good for clarification purposes
     //in real life you'd want to simply return the object {...}
     var directiveDefinitionObject = {
         //We restrict its use to an element
         //as usually  <bars-chart> is semantically
         //more understandable
         restrict: 'E',
         //this is important,
         //we don't want to overwrite our directive declaration
         //in the HTML mark-up
         replace: false,
         //our data source would be an array
         //passed thru chart-data attribute
         scope: {data: '=chartData'},
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           //in D3, any selection[0] contains the group
           //selection[0][0] is the DOM node
           //but we won't need that this time
           var chart = d3.select(element[0]);
           //to our original directive markup bars-chart
           //we add a div with out chart stling and bind each
           //data entry to the chart
            chart.append("div").attr("class", "chart")
             .selectAll('div')
             .data(scope.data).enter().append("div")
             .transition().ease("elastic")
             .style("width", function(d) { return d + "%"; })
             .text(function(d) { return d + "%"; });
           //a little of magic: setting it's width based
           //on the data value (d) 
           //and text all with a smooth transition
         } 
      };
      return directiveDefinitionObject;
   })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `$scope.myData` will be `undefined` when the directive loads, since the service response isn't available yet, so the `data`reference in your directive scope will be `undefined` as well, so basically you're passing nothing to the `d3.data()` method.

There are two approaches I can think of, first would be setting a `$watch` on the `data` inside the directive and wait for the value to change.

```
scope.$watch('data', function(newVal, oldVal) {
  if (newVal !== oldVal) {
    // Render your chart here
  }
});
```

That would render your chart every time the bound value of `data`changes.

The other workaround is emitting and event once the Lsks service is resolved and pass the data in the event, but since you already have a binding in your `$scope`, better use that.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The scope.$watch solved it. I do get an error in the console that something is still undefined, but the chart is now regenerated and the data is displayed correctly. Maybe it is the initial rendering that causes an error, and that it does not matter because soon after the data arrives.

Comment: Can your share a screenshot of the error? I could help you with that as well

Comment: Ok, I guess I cannot do it in a comment, so I will add it as an answer

Comment: Add an appendix to your original post better

Answer (score 0):

This is a continued exploration of errors, while the original problem was solved and the answer accepted.

[The error message received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3euf.png)
I get this initially when the directive is loaded. I am assuming it is because of the asyncronous call.

I will post my code below - it is most likely not very good. I am trying to understand how to use watchers and directives. The challenge is that I am trying to display a d3 graph before I get the data from the DB.

```html
  //camel cased directive name
  //in your HTML, this will be named as bars-chart
  .directive('bulletChart', function($parse) {
      var directiveDefinitionObject = {
          restrict: 'E',
          replace: false,

          //our data source will be
          //passed thru bullet-data attribute 
          scope: {
              bdata: '=bulletData'
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

              var margin = {
                      top: 5,
                      right: 40,
                      bottom: 20,
                      left: 120
                  },
                  width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right,
                  height = 50 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

              var chart = d3.bullet()
                  .width(width)
                  .height(height);
                
                //TESTING - I need some listeners on the bdata value
              scope.$watch('bdata', function(newValue, oldValue) {
                  if ( newValue !== oldValue ) {
                      console.log('bdata has new value');
                  } else {
                      console.log('bdata did not change');
                  }
                      
                  //TESTING - added this To avoid undefined-errors on first time rendering
                  if (!newValue) return;
                  
                  var svg = d3.select(element[0]).selectAll("svg")
                      .data(scope.bdata)
                      .enter().append("svg")
                      .attr("class", "bullet")
                      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                      .append("g")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
                      .call(chart);

                  var title = svg.append("g")
                      .style("text-anchor", "end")
                      .attr("transform", "translate(-6," + height / 2 + ")");

                  title.append("text")
                      .attr("class", "title")
                      .text(function(d) {
                          return d.title;
                      });

              }, true); //for deep dive something
              
              //TESTING - I want a transition when I change a value, but
              //I probably cannot add a second watcher like this. There
              //must be some colission.
              scope.$watch('bdata', function(newValue, oldValue) {

                  d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                      .datum(function(d, i) {
                          d.ranges = scope.data[i].ranges;
                          d.measures = scope[i].measures;
                          d.markers = scope[i].markers;
                          return d;
                      })
                      .call(chart.duration(1000));
              }, true);
          }
      };
      return directiveDefinitionObject;
  })
```

If this is too little information, or too messy, I understand. I will probably in that case clean this up and prepare a new question.

I am generally finding it challenging to work with a d3 graph, getting data from a DB, and changing values in the chart based on the DB data. For example I want different ranges in these bullet charts to be dynamic, calculated based on some values in the DB.

I am basing the code on this tutorial for bullet charts: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4061961

Thanks!